Why is switchMap not working if used with a promise
I am still trying to understand how switchMap works internally, and I thought that it should be possible to return an Observable that is actually a promise.
But my expectations are not met... this function never reaches the code of the tap-operator:
  const res$ = interval(1000).pipe(
     switchMap(() => {
        return from(
           (async () => {
              const rnd = getRandomNumber(1300);
              console.log('Beginning' + rnd);
              await waitForMs(100);
              console.log('After first call ' + rnd);
              await waitForMs(100);
              console.log('After second call ' + rnd);
              return rnd;
           })()
        );
     }),
     tap((x) => {
        console.log('Result' + x);
     })
  );
  res$.subscribe();

waitForMs just returns a simple promise that returns after 100ms:
export async function waitForMs(timeInMs: number) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
         resolve(undefined);
      }, timeInMs);
   });
}


export function getRandomNumber(max: number, min = 0) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

This is strange for me, because the inner observable should not be canceled of the outer switchMap (it just takes 200ms to execute and the interval is a whole second)
So why is "Result" never printed?

what does do the function getRandomNumber, can you add the full code?

Sure, did so ;)

I tried your code, and Result is printed correctly, perhaps is something else in your code that we cannot see, https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zdf2bm?file=index.ts

Indeed, probably something else... Strange and thanks.

a switchmap need to have an observable, you need to convert your promise in observable, you can do it with from(promise)
